# Write subroutine in MIPS that convert integer 0 through 15 into ASCII character '0' through 'F'

Tags: assembly, mips

Write a small subroutine, that converts numbers in the range 0 through 15 into a
printable ASCII-coded character: '0' through '9', or 'A' through 'F', depending on the number.
For numbers not in the range 0 through 15, some bits will be ignored.

Name: The subroutine must be called hexasc .
Parameter: One, in register $a0 . The 4 least significant bits specify a number, from 0 through 15.
All other bits in register $a0 can have any value and must be ignored.
Return value: The 7 least significant bits in register $v0 must be an ASCII code as described below.
All other bits must be zero when your function returns.
Required action: The function must convert input values 0 through 9 into the ASCII codes for digits
'0' through '9', respectively. Input values 10 through 15 must be converted to the ASCII codes for
letters 'A' through 'F', respectively.

```
.text

 main:
      li    $a0,0       # change this to test different values

      jal   hexasc      # call hexasc
      nop               # delay slot filler (just in case)  

      move  $a0,$v0     # copy return value to argument register

      li    $v0,11      # syscall with v0 = 11 will print out
      syscall           # one byte from a0 to the Run I/O window

stop:   j   stop        # stop after one run
       nop              # delay slot filler (just in case)
```

I wrote my `hexasc` subroutine here and for some reason that I'm not understand so it doesn't work. I can't figure it out in which part i have bugs and maybe I'm not doing as it Say's in the specification above.
 Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

```
hexasc:
        addi    $sp,$sp,-4      #make space on the stack
        sw      $a0,0($sp)      #store $a0 on the stack
        li      $t0,0x30        #$t0 = 0x30 ('0' in ascii)
        andi    $a0,$a0,0xf     #only 4 least significant bits is 
                                #needed ignore other bits
loop:       
        add     $a0,$a0,$t0     #$a0 i will think why i did this
        addi    $t0,$t0,1       #increment $t0 by 1
        beq     $t0,0x39,loop2  # if $t0 = 0x39 (9 in ascii)
        j       loop


        li      $t1,0x41       # $t1 = 0x41 ( A in ascii)
loop2:  
        andi    $a0,$a0,0xf    # only 4 LSB ignore other bits
        add     $a0,$a0,$t1    # ???? i will think about this
        beq     $t1,0x46,done  # if $t1 = 0x46 (F in ascii)
        j       loop2

done:           
        add     $v0,$a0,$a0    # return  $a0 in $v0 suspicious ...?
        lw      $a0,0($sp)     # restore the $a0 
        addi    $sp,$sp,4      # put back the stack
        jr      $ra
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint on `hexasc` in the simulator, then single-step through the function to find out why it generates the wrong result.

Comment: Why do you restore `a0` before return? (and store it the beginning). IIRC the MIPS calling convention, the subroutines are OK to modify argument values. Plus the `a0` should contain returning value at end, so restoring it back to original value is a bit .. unfortunate... Anyway definitely try the debugger (I didn't read the routine body, just the push/pop sequence made me chuckle). (now I had a short glimpse at the body... and you may want just to delete it and write on paper all 0 - 15 values, then next to them write all ASCII target values (`48 '0'`, `49 '1'`, ...) and stare at them for 5min

Comment: Can you explain your algorithm by including code comments? Otherwise we can't figure out whether the problem is that you're doing the wrong thing, or you're trying to do the right thing but failing. The first function is well-commented, but the second is just a wall of code.

Comment: Yes, exactly please show the chart with 0 to 15 on one side and the ascii value on the other.  and then explain your algorithm as to how you connect those dots.

Comment: oh.. actually **I was wrong**.. the return value is in `v0`.. and you restore `a0` harmlessly... so .. as you can see, it's easy to **read** the code wrongly... using debugger is better. ;) (I still believe it's ok to modify `a0`, the caller should not expect that the argument will remain intact?)

Comment: Thanks guys for the answers i will use your advices and try to solve it. @Ped7g I just read it in a book that if the `main` use a register so the `function` must use stack before using that register, so i did it for safety, so now if it has no intact on the caller so i will try to remove it, thanks for tips.

Comment: Well, I'm not MIPS programmer, so I googled for a while: *"The values of the argument registers `$a0-$a3` are not required to be preserved across subroutine calls."* https://acm.sjtu.edu.cn/w/images/d/db/MIPSCallingConventionsSummary.pdf (I'm not sure, if this is for linux or mars/spim environment, but I think you should possess the correct documentation yourself, plus the basic things like which registers must be preserved, were same. The stack frame layout is maybe different. But in C/C++ the function arguments are free to be modified by function (caller can't expect preservation).

Comment: One option with less code and more data is to have a string `"0123456789ABCDEF"` and then just index into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one small bug in this two posts that's worth mentioning, `li $v0,0x41` should be `li $v0,0x7`. This due to your specification that an input value of `10` should print out the character `A` in ASCII, but if you have `li $v0,0x41` the output will be `K` instead of `A` for an input value of `10`. 
Here is another version of `hexasc` which prints out those that it's Say's in your spec.

```
hexasc:
      andi  $a0,$a0,0x0f
      addi  $v0,$zero,0x30
      addi  $t0,$zero,0x9

      ble   $a0,$t0,L1
      nop
      addi  $v0,$v0,0x7

L1:
      add   $v0,$a0,$v0
      jr    $ra
nop
```

Answer (score 0):

A few issues ...

You destroyed the `$a0` value during the decimal test so it had the wrong value for the hex section.

Your jumps were doing [infinite] loops. They should have been to `done:`

I've created two versions of your code. One with annotations and one with corrected code [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup].

Here's the annotated version:

```
hexasc:
# NOTE/BUG: stack save/restore of $a0 is not needed due to MIPS ABI
    addi    $sp,$sp,-4              # make space on the stack
    sw      $a0,0($sp)              # store $a0 on the stack
    li      $t0,0x30                # $t0 = 0x30 ('0' in ascii)
    andi    $a0,$a0,0xf             # only 4 least significant bits is
                                    # needed ignore other bits

# NOTE/BUG: altering $a0 further destroys the value for the hex test
loop:
    add     $a0,$a0,$t0             # $a0 i will think why i did this
    addi    $t0,$t0,1               # increment $t0 by 1

# NOTE/BUG: beq is wrong -- we want bgt
# NOTE/BUG: the range test for decimal should be 0x09 and _not_ 0x39
    beq     $t0,0x39,loop2          # if $t0 = 0x39 (9 in ascii)

# NOTE/BUG: looping is wrong -- this should be 'j done'
    j       loop

    li      $t1,0x41                # $t1 = 0x41 ( A in ascii)

# NOTE/BUG: $a0 is now wrong because of add above
loop2:
    andi    $a0,$a0,0xf             # only 4 LSB ignore other bits
    add     $a0,$a0,$t1             # ???? i will think about this

# NOTE/BUG: no range check needed as all values are in range
    beq     $t1,0x46,done           # if $t1 = 0x46 (F in ascii)

# NOTE/BUG: no looping required
    j       loop2

done:
    add     $v0,$a0,$a0             # return  $a0 in $v0 suspicious ...?
    lw      $a0,0($sp)              # restore the $a0
    addi    $sp,$sp,4               # put back the stack
    jr      $ra
```

---

Here's the corrected version:

```
hexasc:
    andi    $a0,$a0,0xf             # only 4 least significant bits is needed

    # check for decimal
    li      $v0,0x30                # set 0x30 ('0' in ascii)
    ble     $a0,0x09,hexasc_done    # value in range 0x0-0x9? if yes, fly

    li      $v0,0x41                # set 0x41 ('A' in ascii)

hexasc_done:
    add     $v0,$v0,$a0             # convert value to ascii
    jr      $ra
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this helped me.